Le COD est-il forcément un complément essentiel ?
Dans les manuels de primaire, on explique qu'on ne peut ni déplacer ni supprimer les compléments essentiels.
On indique aussi que les COD et COI sont des compléments essentiels, avec tout de suite un exemple qui contredit cette règle :

Les girafes mangent des feuilles dans la savane.

Pour moi, dans cet exemple, le COD (des feuilles) peut être supprimé de la phrase et celle-ci a toujours du sens => il n'est donc pas essentiel.
Est-ce qu'il y a une subtilité qui m'échappe ?

« les manuels de primaire », tu as vraiment consulté tous les manuels de primaire ? Car tout dépend de la définition donnée à « complément essentiel », l'enseignement de la grammaire subit l'influence des courants de pensée.  Quelques refs au hasard (loin d'être exhaustif) Définition du Robert : les compléments essentiels du verbe sont des compléments qui ne peuvent être ni déplacés, ni supprimés, mais qui n'assument pas la fonction complément d'objet du verbe.

(Wagner cité par Lavieu) : Parmi les compléments du verbe, on distingue le complément d’objet (direct et indirect), ces deux sortes de compléments ont valeur de complément essentiel, et le complément circonstanciel, non-essentiel, qui s’oppose aux compléments essentiels dont il se distingue par sa mobilité .

Profs de français qui débattent du sujet. On lit aussi souvent la phrase « Les compléments d’objet appartiennent au groupe verbal : ils sont des compléments essentiels, on ne peut ni les déplacer ni (la plupart du temps) les supprimer.) : je souligne « la plupart du temps ». Bref, la grammaire n'est pas une science et chacun peut rester sur ses certitudes.

Des feuilles est essentiel en ce que le sens de la phrase change de manière essentielle (dans l'opinion de ces grammairiens) selon qu'on l'explicite ou qu'on le supprime. En son absence, la phrase dit juste que les giraffes sont adeptes du pique-nique en savane. Ajouté, elle précise que leurs assiettes sont pleines de feuilles; au grand dam des giraffes carnivores du voisinage, je suppose.

Reprenons une définition [BO 1997] des compléments essentiels en grammaire française.
Il s'agit de compléments du verbe qui ont les particularités suivantes:

Ne peuvent pas être supprimés (ce qui nous concerne, à suivre)
Ne peuvent pas être déplacés [en début de phrase] : vrai; "des feuilles les girafes mangent" ou autre permutation est agrammaticale ou incorrecte
Peuvent être pronominalisés (le, la, les, lui, en, y) : vrai; les girafes les mangent

D'autre part, les compléments essentiels ont été introduits dans les programmes (que je n'ai pas connus) comme catégorie-chapeau des:

COD
COI
Compléments de temps, lieu et mesure essentiels (ex: "je me trouve" + lieu; "il pèse" + poids)

Par opposition à la catégorie des Compléments Circonstanciels (supprimables, déplaçables et sans possibilité de les remplacer par un pronom).
Il s'agit principalement de distinguer les compléments d'objet (tous) des compléments de circonstance (tous). On les appelle aussi respectivement compléments de verbe et compléments de phrase.
Mais cette distinction n'est pas parfaitement claire pour tous les spécialistes, et ce maître de conférences a publié un article au titre éloquent, en soulignant:

La fonction COD, bien qu’essentielle, n’est pas obligatoirement
exprimée. [45]

Car parler de tous les compléments d'objet inclut effectivement ceux dont l'expression est optionnelle (apportant un sens différent à la phrase sans eux, sans que celle-ci eût été incorrecte - "elle écrit / un roman") comme ceux qui sont syntaxiquement et sémantiquement obligatoires.
On peut citer comme distinctions entre compléments d'objet optionnels et obligatoires:

"les arguments optionnels sont implicitement présents dans la sémantique du verbe" [p. 242] : ici pour nos girafes, il est évident qu'elles mangent quelque chose, dans la phrase :


Les girafes mangent dans la savane.


A contrario, un complément non essentiel/circonstanciel/de phrase comme dans: "Les girafes mangent l'après-midi" "ne fait qu'apporter une information supplémentaire plutôt que de spécifier un participant [COD de manger] dénoté par le sens du verbe"

Les deux derniers points proviennent de cette thèse d'une autre linguiste, C. Vaguer.
Si on devait conclure à partir de ces éléments, on pourrait dire que "des feuilles" est un complément essentiel, parce que les programmes ont décidé sans consensus que tous les compléments de verbe l'étaient.
Cependant, la première linguiste citée, C. Avezard-Roger, estime que pour respecter cette distinction, le critère de suppression est bien trop hasardeux pour l'imposer formellement aux élèves - elle juge le critère de déplaçabilité bien plus efficace. Expliquer qu'un COD est bien complément essentiel parce que le verbe le sous-entend sans qu'il puisse le lire dans la phrase... me paraît délicat à un élève de primaire.
Nous avons donc dans des exemples comme celui-là un COD:

complément essentiel, dans la mesure où il se pronominalise et ne se déplace pas; sans lui la phrase n'a pas le même sens comme dit en commentaire
optionnel, car sans lui la phrase reste correcte grâce aux verbes en question qui portent en eux ce COD non exprimé

C'est encore Mme Avezard-Roger qui conclut le mieux:

Par ailleurs, nous plaidons pour un allègement des contenus
d’enseignement en grammaire.

